# RtlService.exe leaking handles if explorer not running

Tags: windows-10, drivers, process, services, handle

I have an odd issue with RtlService - apparently a service that connects Windows to the Realtek network card.

I have a Windows 10 IoT machine. When it starts up, it runs an application as a custom shell, instead of `explorer.exe`

However, if I do this, and look in the Task Manager, and view the Handles column I can see that `RtlService.exe`'s handles are increasing at the rate of about 3-4 per second. If left running for long enough, this will build up into the hundreds of thousands and consume a lot of (committed)
RAM, until the memory eventually runs out and the system crashes with an Out of Memory error.

The strange thing is, this only happens if `explorer.exe` is not run - i.e. if I make *any* other application the shell. (I've tried our custom application, Notepad, cmd). If I then run `explorer`, the increase halts. (Killing `explorer` does not make it start increasing again, BTW)

I've used WinDbg, but to be honest I'm a bit of a newbie at this kind of thing, and I all I can tell that the vast majority (and I assume all of the increase after the process first starts up) of the handles are "Section" handles, using the `!handles`  command.

What can I do about this, and how do I stop it from happening? I don't want to just run `explorer` as a solution - this is supposed to be an embedded application which is just running our software.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the service? I see a lot of trash info in searches, but some people commenting it is not a required component for the network to actually work. Might be related to the wireless UI for explorer.

Comment: Yeah that's my next port of call... When I went looking it up, I got the impression it was required (articles describing it as a "bridge" between the Network adapter and the OS and such), but now I'm not so sure.